# Fine Jewelry Editing

Tags: adobe-photoshop

This is the image I'm editing:

[image: My edited image]

I'm trying to edit the image to look like the images below:

[image: Diamond Facet]

[image: Fine Jewelry Editing]

But no matter what I do can't seem to get the paint to match when I paint the shank of the ring nor can I get that Soft but sharp look. Can you please help me out. Thank you!!!!!

Comment: Show where your piece is at and we might be able to offer some advice. Of course I'd also point out that I'm not a jeweler and have no clue what a "shank" is in terms of rings.

Comment: A shank is the metal part of the ring. I'm using a 105mm micro lens so it pics up a lot of details that the human eye can't see I'm having a hard time getting it to look like the images above. Give me a second and I'll post the images that I've worked on.

Comment: As you can see Ryan I'm still trying to get the colors to match as well is give it that sharp smooth glossy look. I'd appreciate any advice or steps in helping me accomplish that similar look. Thank you.

Comment: I'm having really hard time understanding what it is that you are trying to do. I'm not even entirely sure which rings are yours and which ones are the example rings. Maybe you could try to describe or circle out the exact parts you are trying to replicate to your own ring(s) and tell us what you are stuck in.

Comment: The very top ring with the round stone is the one I've edited. The pictures of the rings stacked on each other is the image I'm trying to achieve as far as the color and smoothness of the rings. I want to give it that glossy smooth sharp look but it's not coming out the way I want it to.

Comment: Well a lot of the detail in your example rings come from having multiple rings stacked on top of each other. Also all of those rings have way less metal showing. So it's already quite difficult comparison. Also I feel like the ground plane reflection is a bit too strong in your picture and you have a lot of depth of field going on when the other images don't. It's not that easy to produce believable metallic reflections from nothing... If I were you, I'd consider fixing few things here and there before opening up photoshop. Like adding object(s) around the ring to add detail via reflections.

Comment: I just had a look at your image in photoshop - your curves have no white point or black point, Im guessing that the "pro' shot you are trying to emulate use a fair bit of masking and curve boosting to achieve the contrast - the diamond part is still dirty as well. I also think the light source is altered between shots to achieve the shine.

Comment: I'm going to point you to [a YouTube video by Marios Karampalis](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfeBkNIG4Rs) for some of the technique, but the key, you'll find, is that shiny metal won't look like shiny metal unless there are really dark darks (you know, like actual black), really bright highlights (nearly blown-out white), *and* smooth gradients in the intermediate areas.

Comment: good tips on vid

Answer (score 1):

There are two different techniques at play here.

Both your examples have been photographed in a light tent for the diffused "wrap-around" lighting.

**Light field** - A white seamless background was used. The details have been "shopped" to be dead white. The reflection and drop shadow was added in post. "High key" is a term used by photographers for the look.
**Dark field** - A black seamless background was used. The details in the shadows have been "shopped" to be dead black. The subject was shot on glass as the reflections are real.
***TIP:*** Your tent is featureless. It's too good. Leave a seam in the tent on one or both sides of the camera so there will be a dark "highlight" against the bright reflections to complement the smooth light parts of the metal. There must be an interplay with light and dark to feature the intricacy of the cut stone.

Answer (score 0):

The method of photography is taken under a 'Cloud Dome' [example](http://bermangraphics.com/digital-jury-resources/cloud-dome.htm) - this diffuses the light and allows you to control the shadows. Multiple images are taken from the same angle with the focus concentrating on separate parts and composite post production.

Comment: I do shoot the rings under a dome and also I do use cognisys stack shot device that focuses on different parts of the ring as the device moves closer towards the ring. I also stack images which helps gives it a sharper image. Photographing the product isn't the issue it's editing it to look like the images above that I'm having an issue with. Before the product is given to me it gets polished and cleaned up as much as possible.

Comment: The issue is that when I try to use surface blur to smooth out the metal and then apply a high pass filter on the ring it still doesn't come out looking anywhere close to those images. Also how do I get the diamond to pop out more like the images above of the platinum stacked rings above?

Comment: Skills my friend, skills... Photoshop and lots of time and patience - thats why these guys get the big bucks

Comment: Domes (and tents/boxes) encourage too much flatness, resulting in *meh* images at best; you're almost always better off with discreet diffusers and well-placed black and white cards. Domes are great for catalogue-type drop-and-pop shoots (too many items, not enough time, low price per image), but they're rarely a good idea for high-end shots unless you're just using a *very* large one to eliminate uncontrolled reflections and doing most of the lighting *inside* the dome.